# Why does this int-to-binary attempt fail past 16, and how can I clean it up?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I need this function for some personal work and although doing this in general is trivial, I haven't really played around with bit-shifting before.  I have the following code, which tries to convert an integer into a vector of unsigned integers, where each is 1 or 0 (representing the bit).  I can assume that the integers are always greater than or equal to 0.  Here is my code:

```
vector<unsigned int> toBinary(int x)
{
    stack<unsigned int> s;
    vector<unsigned int> ret_val;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(x); ++i)
    {
        int z = ((x >> i) & 1) ? 1 : 0;
        s.push(z);
    }

    unsigned num_bits = s.size();
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_bits; ++i)
    {
        ret_val.push_back(s.top());
        s.pop();
    }

    return ret_val;
}
```

This works okay for integers up to 16, then it fails.  I use the stack to reverse the order of the bits so the most significant bit is on the left in the final returned value.  Why is this broken, and how can I clean it up? Thank you

Comment: This site is for getting reviews of working code. "Why does this code not work" kind of questions belong on SO - not here. Migrating there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x is an int - presumably 32 bits, *i.e.* 4 bytes, in size. sizeof x = 4, 4 bits allow for numbers 0..15

What you want is 8*sizeof x, because of the 8 bits in a byte - although there is a better way (see below).

Cleaning up-wise:

1. Avoid `using namespace std`, if you must use it then narrow it down to single use (*e.g.* `using std::vector`). This means decorating things with `std::`, but it's worth it for readability.
2. Use `unsigned int` rather than `int`, be explicit about what you're using.
3. Returning a vector of `bool` seems to make more sense.
4. The number of bits in a unsigned int is given by `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits` (`#include <limits>`).
5. You can avoid the use of a stack easily enough by using `std::reverse` on the vector (`#include <algorithm>`).

Putting it all together, your function could look something like:

```
std::vector<bool> toBinary(unsigned int x)
{
    std::vector<bool> ret_val;

    for ( unsigned int z = x; z > 0; z /= 2 ) {

        bool r = ( ( z & 1 ) == 1 );
        ret_val.push_back(r);
    }

    int bits = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits;
    ret_val.resize(bits);

    std::reverse( ret_val.begin(), ret_val.end() );

    return ret_val;
}
```